# Array in HTML form is only producing the very first result when checking with var_dump()

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms

Here is the HTML and jQuery that produces the form (all it does is allows users to create another input field that has the same names: `skillName[]` and `skillLevel[]`):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 100;
  var wrapper = $(".wrapper");
  var add_button = $(".new-skill-field");

  var i = 1;
  $(document).on("click", ".new-skill-field", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    if (i < max_fields) {
      i++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div><label>Skill Name:</label><input type="text" name="skillName[]"><label>Skill Level:</label><input type="text" name="skillLevel[]" class="input-small"><button class="remove-skill">Remove This Skill</button><br></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove-skill", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    i--;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <label>Skill Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="skillName[]" id="skillName">
    <label>Skill Level:</label>
    <input type="text" name="skillLevel[]" id="skillLevel" class="input-small">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="new-skill-field">Add Another Skill</button>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfp1cmmL/)

Regardless of how many fields I create and enter values into, if my PHP script is nothing else but `var_dump($_POST['skillName'])`, it only returns one value: the first input field.  I **know** this works, as I have done this in the past.  I just cannot figure out why this form, or perhaps this jQuery, is causing it to only pass one value in the array.

And yes, I do need the arrays to be coded in the form... there is no other way of passing the array to my class and have it do what I need it to.

Comment: Where is your PHP?

Comment: @nerdlyist I said the only thing I am trying to do now is simply var_dump() the array to see what is even being displayed, which is only 1 value from the form.

Comment: That was massively confusing. Just `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: I am doing that.  Like my original post says, even if I have 3 input fields of data, for some reason only 1 is being passed into the variable when I do var_dump($_POST).

Comment: I see what you are doing now. Can you post the form html you have for when you submit this?

Comment: Okay this is one of the weirdest things that has happened in my (albeit short) programming career... I didn't touch anything whatsoever, I refreshed the page to check the HTTP Live Headers since I had cleared them.  It randomly picked up the array, after refreshing the same code (on 3 different browsers on this computer, 2 on my MacBook, and on my phone).  I honestly have no idea what is going on at this point, but it seems to be working... for now.  Thanks for taking the time to try and help!

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because it was basically guesswork and doesn't add anything to SO.  Glad this seems to have worked for you!

Comment: I just wish I knew what exactly happened to cause it to pick the other array indices up, because if it stops displaying them again I have zero clue what changed.  Here's to hoping that doesn't happen... Thanks again Juan!

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is one of the weirdest things that has happened in my (albeit short) programming career... I didn't touch anything whatsoever in the code, I refreshed the page to check the HTTP Live Headers since I had cleared them.  It randomly picked up the array, after refreshing the same code (on 3 different browsers on this computer, 2 on my MacBook, and on my phone).  I honestly have no idea what is going on at this point, but it seems to be working... for now.  Thanks for taking the time to try and help!

Here's to hoping the problem doesn't arise again, because I have no clue what changed to cause it to pick up the array indices!

Comment: One thing that seems peculiar is the absence of `<form>` elements.  Maybe if all your dynamically-created divs were inside a `<form>`, you'd have better browser compatibility.  Good luck!

Comment: I left the form elements out on accident, but they were your typical `<form action="script.php" method="POST"> ... </form>` .  I am almost afraid to touch the code in that file now that it's working, but need to add some more stuff.  I think I may take a half hour break or something and rest my mind a bit, because I've been beating my head against the wall for 2 hours now trying to figure this out.